# Audio gets paused after opening socket to Bluetooth headset (Android 2.x)

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth

I have written an app to connect to a speaker dock via bluetooth.  The app controls the EQ, Bass/Treble, etc.

Once paired with the dock, the Android device automatically starts playing music via it's built in media player, as it sees the dock as a headset.

However, once I launch my app, the audio gets paused on most 2.x devices.

After I open a socket to the device, I ask it for the firmware/hardware version.   In looking at the log, I see that these commands are received successfully, and then this shows up:

```
04-04 07:23:16.566: E/BluetoothIntentReceiver(5616): onReceive() Action : android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON
04-04 07:23:16.566: D/BluetoothIntentReceiver(5616): onReceive() KeyEvent : KeyEvent{action=0 code=85 repeat=0 meta=0 scancode=200 mFlags=8}
04-04 07:23:16.566: E/BluetoothIntentReceiver(5616): onReceive() Command : togglepause,mDown=false
04-04 07:23:16.632: E/BluetoothIntentReceiver(5616): onReceive() Action : android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON
04-04 07:23:16.632: D/BluetoothIntentReceiver(5616): onReceive() KeyEvent : KeyEvent{action=1 code=85 repeat=0 meta=0 scancode=200 mFlags=8}
04-04 07:23:16.632: E/BluetoothIntentReceiver(5616): onReceive() Command : togglepause,mDown=true
```

That is what pauses the music.  I am not sure where these KeyEvents are being generated from, because I am not even holding the device.

As I mentioned this only seems to happen on 2.x devices.

Does anyone know why the audio is getting paused, and how I can stop it?

Comment: `code=85` should be `KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE`. What does your app do right before you see the intent in the logs?

Comment: @Michael-- Nothing really.   I am sending data to/receiving from the dock.   But I don't have code anywhere in the app to generate key presses.

Answer (score 0):

I never figured out why the keyevent was getting generated, but luckily my app was able to catch it.  I created an onKeyDown method, and looked for KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE.   If I found that code within the first 5 seconds of launching my app, I return true.

This worked for my situation, but didn't find the root cause.